# What is the fastest way to compute the mean value by "column" in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, mean

I would like to know if there's a more efficient way to compute the mean value in a list of tuples. I want to get the mean value by "column".

```py
lst_tuples = [(0.8485923111450038, 0.5580229254566210, 0.5956876562851486),
             (0.43485114500389231, 0.6554580221029266, 0.7285148695687656),
             (0.9485923111450038, 0.3522102925456680, 0.5687656285119486)]

v_s = 0
a_s = 0
d_s = 0
c = 1

for v, a, d in lst_tuples:
    v_s += v
    a_s += a
    d_s += d

    v_mean = v_s / c
    a_mean = a_s / c
    d_mean = d_s / c
    c += 1

#print(v_mean, a_mean, d_mean)
print(v_mean)

0.7440119224312999
```

Comment: `np.mean([a[0] for a in lst_tuples])`?

Comment: Also `np.array(lst_tuples).mean(axis=0)` gives you all three means?

Comment: @QuangHoang the last one was the one I was looking for

Comment: Why did you add a numpy tag but not show a numpy attempt?